# PHP Magento 2 REST Consumer key has expired

Tags: php, magento

I have been usng this [OAuth Library](https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth1-client) for connecting with Magento 2.1 REST API. My code for getting Temporary Credentials is as below-

```
if (isset($_GET['go'])) {
    // First part of OAuth 1.0 authentication is retrieving temporary credentials.
    // These identify you as a client to the server.
    $temporaryCredentials = $server->getTemporaryCredentials();
    // Store the credentials in the session.
    $_SESSION['temporary_credentials'] = serialize($temporaryCredentials);
    session_write_close();

    // Second part of OAuth 1.0 authentication is to redirect the
    // resource owner to the login screen on the server.
    $server->authorize($temporaryCredentials);
    // Step 1
} else {
    // Display link to start process
    echo '<a href="?go=go">Login</a>';
}
```

My Header for getting Temporary Credentials is as below-

```
[headers] => Array ( [Authorization] => OAuth oauth_consumer_key="l4y2cxabrklrch98r9s8wmuamgffra7v", oauth_nonce="uDiiz1wTGfFwCMbWXgv5JaB9EMq8u1PK", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1485165675", oauth_version="1.0", oauth_callback="http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A24260%2Fsubamx%2FMPSMage%2FCode%2FAuth%2Fresources%2Fexamples%2Fmagento.php", oauth_signature="afMf5BuvUBlgoD1E9LKd9CjrVtU%3D" [Accept] => application/json )
```

And I am getting this error-

```
[message:protected] => Client error: `POST http://magento_store/oauth/token/request` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response: oauth_problem=Consumer+key+has+expired 
[string:Exception:private] => [code:protected] => 401 [file:protected] => C:\xampp\htdocs\subamx\MPSMage\Code\Auth\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Exception\RequestException.php [line:protected] => 111
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue, were you able to resolve it?